# how to swap text inside files

Tags: files, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

Inside my file I need to swap places of all instances of :

```
grep 'search string'
```

and

```
sed '/string of text/,/string of text/{//!d}'
```

In VI I have tried a regex with no luck - it says something about trailing characters.

```
:%s/grep 'search string'/sed '/string of text/,/string of text/{//!d}'/g
```

I have also tried with sed outside the file: which says event not found

```
sed -i 's/grep 'search string'/sed '/search string/,/search string/{//!d}'/g' filename.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work? I have too many instances I need to change and doing it manually is not an option.

I want to change this line of code:

```
succ_1st=`grep 'resulted in successful answer' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```

to this:

```
succ_1st=`sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | grep 'resulted in successful answer' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```

THese are lines of code from a script BTW

Comment: Please see edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For your first question

To make that command work, a change delimiter helps.  Also, the single-quotes inside the sed command need to be properly escaped to protect them from the shell:

```
sed  's|grep '\''search string'\''|sed '\''/search string/,/search string/{//!d}'\''|g' file
```

For example, using this test file:

```
$ cat file
grep 'search string'
```

The above command produces:

```
$ sed  's|grep '\''search string'\''|sed '\''/search string/,/search string/{//!d}'\''|g' file
sed '/search string/,/search string/{//!d}'
```

To change the file in place, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's|grep '\''search string'\''|sed '\''/search string/,/search string/{//!d}'\''|g' file
```

#### For your second question

```
sed -r 's/(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/' filename
```

For example, consider this test file:

```
$ cat filename
succ_1st=`grep 'resulted in successful answer' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```

This command produces:

```
$ sed -r 's/(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/' filename
succ_1st=`sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | grep 'resulted in successful answer' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```

To change the file in-place, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -ir 's/(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/' filename
```

#### Vi commands

The first command above can be performed in vim with:

```
%s/grep 'search string'/sed '\/search string\/,\/search string\/{\/\/!d}'/g
```

The swap command can be performed inside vim with:

```
%s/\v(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this swap from inside VI using regex?

Comment: @user53029 I wrote and tested both of those commands on the shell command-line _outside_ of VI.

Comment: @user53029 Update: I added to the answer substitute commands that work inside vim.

Answer (score 1):

Not sed, mostly bash:

```
string=$(cat <<'END'
succ_1st=`grep 'resulted in successful answer' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
END
)

var=$(cut -d'`' -f1 <<<"$string")
code=$(cut -d'`' -f2 <<<"$string")
IFS='|' read -ra commands <<<"$code"
filename=$( set -f; eval set -- "${commands[0]}"; echo ${!#} )  # danger
tmp=${commands[0]//${filename//\//\\\/}/}
commands[0]="${commands[1]} $filename"
commands[1]=$tmp
printf -v new '%s`%s`' "$var" "$(IFS='|'; echo "${commands[*]}")"
echo "$new"
```

```
succ_1st=` sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}'  $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp|grep 'resulted in successful answer'  | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```